# Is it possible to use the show/hide javascript to show 2 elements with the same onclick command?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, show-hide

The following script is basic javascript to show/hide elements.  My question is if I can show 2 elements with the same onclick function?  Is this possible and if so how should I write my code to make it work because none of my variations have worked?  Much thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    function hideStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }

    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick= "{black1(); red1();}; {showStuff('character1', 'character1-img');   hideStuff('character2');}">1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array as an arg, instead of a single id, and just loop over the ids, showing/hiding each one.  Something like

```
function showStuff(ids) {
    var len = ids.length,
        id;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){ 
       id = ids[i];
       document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showStuff(id) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    document.getElementById( args.pop() ).style.display = 'block';
    if ( args.length ) showStuff.apply(null, args);
}​
```

This function will recursively call itself when you pass multiple ids, showing each element until there are none left.

You'd use it like this: `showStuff('firstID', 'secondID', 'thirdID')` (which is what you're already doing in your example).

http://jsfiddle.net/kennis/vg9Z4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick= "black1();red1();showStuff('character1');showStuff('character1-img');hideStuff('character2');">1</a>
```

But you're better off having something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick= "clickedLink123();">1</a>
```

With this in your script:

```
function clickedLink123() {
    black1();
    red1();
    showStuff('character1');
    showStuff('character1-img');
    hideStuff('character2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything in JavaScript until and unless it is a valid JavaScript.

You can have a single function say `onAnchorClick` which you can call on anchor click and passing the elements to show/hide as an array then execute your logic inside this function.

```
<a href="#" onclick= "onAnchorClick(['character1', 'character1-img'], ['character2']);">1</a>
```

Js

```
function onAnchorClick(elementsToShow, elementsToHide){
    //do stuff here       
    black1();
    red1();

    if(elementsToShow){ 
        showStuff(elementToShow);
    }
    if(elementsToHide){ 
        hideStuff(elementToShow);
    }
}
function showStuff(ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
       document.getElementById(id[i]).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
function hideStuff(ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
       document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```